# Javascript element giving text from before it was updated

Tags: javascript, html

I've just been trying to make some code to test out tampermonkey stuff on simple maths questions when I came across this error. it would work for the first question, get the question, solve it, enter the answer. The element then changes to a new question however when I use .innerHTML or .textContent it always gives the original question.

Here is my code which shows this:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('currgamename'))
console.log(document.getElementById('currgamename').textContent)
```

I get this output:

```
<span id="currgamename">12-7</span>
6-3 //The first question that appears
```

Full code:

```
var delayInMilliseconds = 1000; //1 second

    var x = 0

    setTimeout(function() {
        var handler = setInterval(function() {
            document.getElementById('playPadding').childNodes[1].click()
            var equation = document.getElementById('currgamename').textContent
            var actual = equation.split('-')
            var answer = (parseInt(actual[0]) - parseInt(actual[1])).toString()
            document.getElementById('currgamename').innerHTML = 'hello'
            console.log(document.getElementById('currgamename'))
            console.log(document.getElementById('currgamename').textContent)
            document.getElementById('gameinput').value = answer
            document.getElementById('nextButton').click()
            x++;
            if (x >= 5) {
                clearInterval(handler);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }, delayInMilliseconds);
```

I have absolutely no clue why it gives the updated element but not the updated text so I could really use some clarification here thanks!

Comment: Try setting the textContent or innerHTML as well and see if that changes anything

Comment: alright so I added just before those 2 lines `document.getElementById('currgamename').textContent = 'hello'` and now it just gives
`<span id="currgamename">10-7</span>`
and
`hello`
I am so confused!

Comment: Set the innerHTML instead and see it work

Comment: it made no difference

Comment: It works for me, are we not seeing all the code?

Comment: Could it be to do with the fact that this is in a setInterval

Comment: No, can we see all the relevant code?

Comment: it's been added

Comment: Is your script at the bottom of your <body> tag?

Comment: It works perfectly for me

Comment: Your code cannot pinpoint the error without the code attached to the `nextbutton` and without the relevant html. The page likely has multiple elements with the `currgamename` id (*erroneously*) and you only read the first.

Comment: It's a tampermonkey script and I literally only found out about it today. I don't know where the javascript would be contained

Comment: what is the page on which you run this code ?

Comment: I will look into that and check

Comment: https://www.sporcle.com/games/g/minmathminus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I genuinely cannot believe my stupidity, I've been at this for 4 hours now and the error was that I had `document.getElementById('playPadding').childNodes[1].click()` inside the setinterval. It was pressing the start button everytime i wanted to answer a new question so it was just replacing it with the old one FML.

Answer (score 0):

In the console:

```
>document.querySelector("#currgamename")
<-<span id="currgamename">12-7</span>

>document.querySelector("#currgamename").textContent = "hello"
<-"hello"
------And the HTML on the screen changed to show the "hello" instead of "12-7"------

>document.querySelector("#currgamename").innerHTML = "bye"
<-"bye"

>document.querySelector("#currgamename").innerText
<"bye"
```

So it works as long as your querySelector is aimed at the correct element it should work